# How to send array of object to another class's member function. C++

Tags: c++

I need help with this code. I am making a Book Shop Inventory system. I have made two classes so far.

(1) Books

(2) Inventory

All the information of a single book is stored in 'Books' and the information of all the books (array of books) is stored in Inventory. I will need to make a few functions like "Buy Books", "Search Books" etc.
I am getting an error when I try to subtract the bought books from StockPosiiton (aka books in stock).

It gives me an error:

> In member function 'void Inventory::Buy_Book(Books*, int)':|
>
> main.cpp|114|error: invalid use of member (did you forget the '&' ?)|

**Q: What is the best way to subtract the bought books from the stock?**

```
void Buy_Book(Books B[], int I)             //It is of Inventory Class
    {
        char Choice;
        int Stock_New;
        cout<<"Complete Transaction? [Y/N]"<<endl;
        if (Choice=='Y')
        {
            Stock_New=B[i].getStockPosition-Copies;    //I am getting problem here
        }
        else if (Choice='N')
        {

        }
        else
            cout<<"Wrong choice!"<<endl;
    }
```

Now, I am posting the rest of the Inventory class.

```
class Inventory
{
    Books books[10];
    static int Successful_Transactions;
    static int Unsuccessful_Transactions;
    string Search_Title;
    int Copies;
public:
    Inventory()
    {
        //we cannot initialize static members here
    }
    void Buy_Book(Books B[], int i)
    {
        char Choice;
        int Stock_New;
        cout<<"Complete Transaction? [Y/N]"<<endl;
        if (Choice=='Y')
        {
            Stock_New=B[i].getStockPosition-Copies;
        }
        else if (Choice='N')
        {

        }
        else
            cout<<"Wrong choice!"<<endl;
    }
    void Search_Book()
    {
        bool Result=false;
        cout<<"Enter the Title of the book: ";
        cin>>Search_Title;
        for (int i=0 ; i<=9 ; i++)
        {
            if(Search_Title==books[i].getTitle())
            {
                cout<<"Book found"<<endl;
                Result=true;
                books[i].display_info();
                cout<<"\nNumber of Copies Required: ";
                cin>>Copies;
                if(Copies<=books[i].getStockPosition())
                {
                    cout<<"Total Price: "<<Copies*books[i].getStockPosition()<<endl;
                    Buy_Book(books, i);
                }
                else
                    cout<<"Not enough copies available"<<endl;
            }
        }
        if(Result==false)
            cout<<"Book not found"<<endl;
    }


};

int Inventory::Successful_Transactions=0;
int Inventory::Unsuccessful_Transactions=0;
```

Comment: Make your life *much* easier and forget C-style arrays exist and instead always use `std::array` and/or `std::vector`.

Comment: What is `Books::getStockPosition` in `Stock_New=B[i].getStockPosition-Copies;`? Looks like it's a getter _function_. Did you maybe mean `Stock_New=B[i].getStockPosition()-Copies;`?

Comment: The point is it's a university assignment, and I can't use things which we haven't learned yet lol.

Comment: Ah yes it's a getter function. Maybe the code missed the parenthesis here.. @churill

Comment: @FloraBlackrose "The point is it's a university assignment, and I can't use things which we haven't learned yet" - such arbitrary restrictions should be mentioned as part of the question.

Comment: Next time I'll do that.